# SQL how to "join" result of two queries on the same table?

Tags: sql

Suppose we have a table listing orders, among others one column lists the customer who bought a product, another column lists the specific product he/she bought.

It is easy to get the number of customers who bought a specific product, but how do I get the number that bought a set of 2 related specific products? (Actually in the concrete case there are exactly two products of interest in the table, and I want to find out, how many got both of them).

Can this somehow be done using the join command and if so, how?

Many thanks
Reiner

I have no idea how to structure the query.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join:

```
select customer_id
from (select distinct customer_id from orders where product_id = 1) p1
join (select distinct customer_id from orders where product_id = 2) p2
  using (customer_id);
```

Or aggregate:

```
select customer_id
from orders
group by customer_id
having count(case when product_id = 1 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when product_id = 2 then 1 end) > 0;
```

Or use lookups, provided there is a customers table as there should be:

```
select *
from customers
where customer_id in (select customer_id from orders where product_id = 1)
  and customer_id in (select customer_id from orders where product_id = 2);
```

As to counting: In the first and third query you can `select count(*)`. In the second query you can select from the results: `select count*) from ( <the second query> ) q`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a self-join to find customers who have purchased both items:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT T0.customer AS customers_both_products
FROM orders AS T0
JOIN orders AS T1 ON T0.customer = T1.customer
WHERE T0.product = 'ProductA'
  AND T1.product = 'ProductB';
```

and to get the customers count, simply use the COUNT function:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T0.customer) AS customers_both_products_count
FROM orders AS T0
JOIN orders AS T1 ON T0.customer = T1.customer
WHERE T0.product = 'ProductA'
  AND T1.product = 'ProductB';
```